# 3 column layout issue

Tags: html, css

i have issue with three column layout.

Issue: i have set "position:fixed" for "left" and "right" div.  when i re-size the window the "right" div is overlapping to "center" div.

i need the "right" div should not overlap to "center" div.

is this possible?

HTML:

```
<div id="master">
<div class="left-div">Lorem ipsum..</div>
<div class="center-div">Lorem ipsum..</div>
<div class="right-div">Lorem ipsum..</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#master{
    width:100%;     
    }

.left-div{
    width:150px;
    background:red; 
    height:500px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;      
    }

.center-div{
    width:640px;    
    background:yellow;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:170px;
    float:left; 
    }

.right-div{
    width:300px;
    background:green;
    height:500px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    }
```

Comment: want like this? http://jsbin.com/xepofaxa/1/edit

Comment: Like this only. but i need to set "position:fixed" for "left" and "right". after that when i resize the window below "1024px" resultion, i need horizontal scrollbar. in that case. the "right" div should not overlap the "center" div.  is this possible?

Comment: Did u check my answer?

Comment: Yes. i have see. but i need set pixel width for "Right" and "Left" div. 

is this possible?

Comment: @user3839302 It is not possible. It ll not work for all the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can adjust your center div with following

```
.center-div{  
    background:yellow;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-right:320px;
    }
```

but this will overlap in small screen, for small screen you need to use media-query

[**working jsFiddle File**](http://jsfiddle.net/6yGab/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Check this link-DEMO]** http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/XL4Y4/

Specify width in percentage. It ll solve your problem.

```
#master
{
width:100%;     
}

.left-div
{
 width:20%;
 background:red; 
 height:500px;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 top:0;    
}

.center-div
{
 width:50%;    
 background:yellow;
 height:500px;
 margin-left:20%;
 float:left; 
}

.right-div
{
  width:30%;
  background:green;
  height:500px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

It will fit for all sized windows since width is specified in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the exact position and size of every element (using the same attributes like left and top) in order to preserve the original positions and sizes of elements without overlapping. This is not wise due to different screen sizes. You should use position: absolute instead of fixed. With javascript (or jquery) you can get the current screen width and give every element a prefered part of it.

Comment: he tagged in html and css. Not jquery or Javascript